# Can modifiedCount and upsertedCount both be 0?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, upsert, mongodb-update

I've been wondering, using `update` of `mongodb` with the `{upsert:true}` options, is it possible to get both `upsertedCount` AND `modifiedCount` be 0?

I understand that the `upsertedCount` refers to the created documents, while the `modifiedCount` refers to the updated documents.

So using the `upsert` I cannot find a scenario in which both of those will be equal to 0.

Am i wrong?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You can have a situation when you don't have anything to upsert so `upsertedCount = 0` and  the update you did to existing document modified the value of the field to same value as before which will have `modifiedCount = 0`. So in this situation you'll have `matchedCount != 0`

Comment: @Veeram Saying "you dont have anything to upsert" you mean the document already exists? Plus you claim that `update` of mongo actually updates only relevant values? I figured mongo just overrides the document with the new one.. And say you're right, if it only updates the relevant values, it won't be updating a field of the same value, am I right?

Comment: *"you dont have anything to upsert" you mean the document already exists?* Yes.  *Plus you claim that update of mongo actually updates only relevant values? I figured mongo just overrides the document with the new one.*  Mongo has both selective update and replacement.  *And say you're right, if it only updates the relevant values, it won't be updating a field of the same value, am I right?* Yes and the modified count will be 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are correct in your assumption.
Upsert basically means create a new document if a document cannot be found.
So if you set it to true while doing an update either the document is present and will be modified (setting modifiedCount to 1) or the document is not present (setting upsertCount to 1)

Comment: So you claim there's no scenario in which both of them will be 0

Comment: This is not correct, please see answers below (`$setOnInsert` and `arrayFilters`).

Answer (score 0):

There is a case where both are zero.
If you use some filter *within the update operation*, as opposed to within the query, and this filter does not match, it might find the document, setting *matchedCount* to 1, and *upsertedCount* to 0, but because the sub-query does not match, your *modifiedCount* will be 0 as well.

Example database:

```
{
    _id: 2
    items: [1, 2]
}
```

Example query:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    {_id: 2},
    { $set: { items.$[elem]: 4 } },
    { arrayFilters: [{elem: 3}], upsert: true }
)
```

Result:

```
{ acknowledged: true,
  insertedId: null,
  matchedCount: 1,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedCount: 0 }
```

This query is a sort of weird way to replace the 3 with a 4, but if the 4 does not exist, the document is found but not modified.

Answer (score 0):

With `$setOnInsert` this is actually quite realistic to happen. If that's the only operation you're using, you'll always get both being 0 if the document already existed.

```js
db.collection.updateOne(
  { name: "David" },
  { $setOnInsert: { firstSeenAt: new Date() } },
  { upsert: true }
)
```

will return the following (with both `upsertedCount` and `modifiedCount` being 0)

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  insertedId: null,
  matchedCount: 1,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedCount: 0
}
```